# Using SAS for an Azure Blob using CDN?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Is it possible to serve a private blob using Azure CDN with a SAS query? I want to prevent hotlinking for my files but I think adding a CDN in between this will not be possible.  Perhaps there is another solution, either with Azure or AWS S3?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, yes. You can use SAS with CDN. If you generate a SAS token for a blob, you can append that to the CDN URL for the blob. For example:

**Generated SAS token for blob**: ?sv=2012-02-12&st=2013-04-12T23%3A37%3A08Z&se=2013-04-13T00%3A12%3A08Z&sr=b&sp=rw&sig=dF2064yHtc8RusQLvkQFPItYdeOz3zR8zHsDMBi4S30%3D

**CDN URL for blob**: http://az623979.vo.msecnd.net/cdn/blob.txt

**Final URL**: http://az623979.vo.msecnd.net/cdn/blob.txt?sv=2012-02-12&st=2013-04-12T23%3A37%3A08Z&se=2013-04-13T00%3A12%3A08Z&sr=b&sp=rw&sig=dF2064yHtc8RusQLvkQFPItYdeOz3zR8zHsDMBi4S30%3D

Comment: Turns out it works but even after the sas is expire, you can still use it. Any way for it to expire?

Comment: An object already cached in the CDN will remain cached until the time-to-live(TTL) period for the object expires. By default, this is 7 days. Check out this link to learn how to set a different TTL period https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg680306.aspx

Comment: Would reducing the TTL to mere minutes affect the speed of the CDN, to the point of it not being helpful?

Comment: Well it depends on your scenario I suppose. If the majority of the object retrieval is done during that TTL period then it will be helpful. Once the TTL period expires though, the object will no longer be cached will affect the speed of the CDN.

Comment: Basically, my use case is about hosting audio files, a sas is generated when a user wants to play the file. So if a lot of users are listening to the file, each one has a unique sas, so most of the hits would have to retrieve the file from the storage account, instead of cache.

Comment: Yeah you're CDN probably won't be as effective with this scenario. Maybe there's someone more familiar with Azure CDN who can provide you with more guidance for your scenario.